# Open NextGen gallery in same page?

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

When I click on the album it takes me to the gallery page and it displays the image in a lightbox. Is it possible to show to the images at the same page instead of it taking me to the gallery page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to:
Admin panel -> Gallery -> Options -> Gallery and set the checkbox: "Deactivate gallery page link"   "The album will not link to a gallery subpage. The gallery is shown on the same page."

Comment: Don't see checkbox. Maybe it was removed after update?

Comment: In later plugin versions, the option is called something like "activate AJAX navigation".